# Wordpress + Customize Theme + Admin Menu with sub menus

Tags: wordpress

I have to modify a wordpress theme that has been done by someone else.
I am trying to figure it out where the admin menu has been setup.
There are 2 customized admin menu:
Admin Menu 1 contains 2 sub menus
Admin Menu 2 contains 3 sub menus.

I searched into the functions.php I cannot find the name "Admin Menu 1". I have no idea where is it defined.
I checked into the plugin folder and there is no plugin related to it.

Do you have any idea how to do reverse engineering and find where is it define? I need to change the label for the 2 menus.

I thought it will be an easy ride :)

Let me know if you have any ideas, I searched 2 days on google, youtube but I could not find any other option on where it can be defined.

Thank you.

Comment: the brutal way would be to download the entire theme folder and then perform a directory-wide search on file contents. I for one use Searchmonkey to perform such tasks. https://sourceforge.net/projects/searchmonkey/

Comment: I tried but I cannot find it

Comment: I found a plugin CPT UI that contains the 2 type of functions Admin Menu 1 and Admin Menu 2 but not sure for what exactly.

Comment: I found the way it works basically you create the CPT Type of post then add a category with CPT plugin. Once it is done you go to Custom Fields and you link the type of posts with the custom fields you want to create there.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I found the way it works basically you create the CPT Type of post then add a category with CPT plugin. Once it is done you go to Custom Fields and you link the type of posts with the custom fields you want to create there. –